# $.text(["someText"]) - What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've recently come across a code sample I had to use, and I was able to use it, but I didn't quite understand exactly what was going on.

Here's part of the code:

```
.sortElements(function(a, b){
    return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ? 
        inverse ? -1 : 1 
        : inverse ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I know that this function is deciding which element should be sorted first out of `a` and `b`, and I know that inverse is deciding the sort order, but I don't know what `$.text([a])` is doing. Is it parsing `a` as text kind of like `parseInt(a)` and `Date.parse(a)`?

Google could not help me. I've also looked into the `jQuery` site and all I've found is

`$(selector).text()`, `$(selector).text(newText)` function.

Here's the Fiddle I'm basing my code from http://jsfiddle.net/gFzCk/

Comment: What plug-ins are you using? jQuery doesn't have a `jQuery.text` function at all (at least, not a *documented* one). (It has a `text` function of jQuery *instances*, but that's different.)

Comment: It's creating an array with the variable as it's only value - why is a very good question.

Comment: It looks like it's an undocumented function in jQuery for getting the text from element(s), without the need for a jQuery object containing them. So, assuming `a` is a DOM node with some text inside, `$(a).text()` and `$.text([a])` are equivalent. See [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eCwRZ/).

Comment: Sorry I should have given the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gFzCk/

Comment: @owen add this fiddle to question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspecting the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) will reveal that the `$(selector).text()` that you're familiar with, uses `$.text` internally:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    text: function( value ) {
        return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
            return value === undefined ?
                jQuery.text( this ) :
                this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) );
        }, null, value, arguments.length );
    },
```

It is an undocumented function (which means further jQuery revisions may drop it at will, without notifying you). You'll find its definition as such:

```
jQuery.text = Sizzle.getText;
```

`Sizzle.getText`, in turn, is documented as "Utility function for retrieving the text value of an array of DOM nodes". Seeing as `Sizzle.getText` is a documented feature, I would recommend using that rather than the jQuery shorthand, as I don't expect jQuery to drop Sizzle any time soon.

This function, then, is the piece of code that yields the text content of a DOM node. Your sorting method is sorting DOM nodes by the alphabetical order of their text content. I don't know why the author has decided to get the text of an array containing only one element (`[a]`), rather than passing the element immediately (`a`), which would work equally well.

Answer (score 9):

`jQuery.text` does the heavy lifting for the [implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L32-L38) for the `.text()` method -- it seems to be an undocumented function with the core functionality for `.text()`, but missing some jQuery polish.

It's ["imported" from Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle-jquery.js#L7), where it appears as `Sizzle.getText`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Well, theoretically you could use it to retrieve the text of a DOM node without incurring the overhead of creating a jQuery object to call `.text()` on it. But practically... I don't see that as being much of a benefit.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your jsfiddle it appears it's a function for getting the text from an element, simular to .text()

`console.log(a)` logged `<td>28/02/2013</td>`

While

`console.log($.text[a])` logged `28/02/2013`

Answer (score 1):

If the code above does something useful (= there is no indication it does according to the jQuery documentation), then it probably calls `.text()` on `a` and `b`.

I'm wondering why the author didn't use `$(a).text()` because that *should* do the same. Maybe the code also works no matter whether `a` is a jquery wrapped node or not :-/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the brackets. if `a` is an element, `[a]` is a element array, so the calls to `$.text(...)` are passing an array as parameter.

I couldn't find any documentation about `jQuery.text` but only for [`jQuery.fn.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). However, you can see that the implementation of [`jQuery.text`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.text) handles arrays as parameters as well as scalar values.

In this case, `$.text([a])` is probably just the same as `$.text(a)`.